# dismissViewControllerAnimated causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS - swift

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, presentviewcontroller

Im trying to dismiss a UIViewController with dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {}) but I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to do it. (that is, in 1 out of 10 times its working).

I have used a custom transitionDelegate, and when Im not setting that, its working.

The ListTransitionDelegate returns animators and presentationController.

The PresentationController looks like this

```
    init(presentingViewController: UIViewController!, presentedViewController: UIViewController!, controllerStyle: SideControllerStyle, shortest: CGFloat) {
    self.controllerStyle = controllerStyle
    self.shortest = shortest

    super.init(presentingViewController: presentingViewController, presentedViewController: presentedViewController)

    self.dimmingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("closePresented"))
    dimmingView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

override func adaptivePresentationStyle() -> UIModalPresentationStyle
{
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.OverFullScreen
}

override func shouldPresentInFullscreen() -> Bool
{
    return true
}

override func presentationTransitionWillBegin() {
    var containerView = self.containerView
    self.dimmingView.frame = self.containerView.bounds
    containerView.insertSubview(self.dimmingView, atIndex:0)

    presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator().animateAlongsideTransition({context in
        self.dimmingView.alpha = 0.5
        }, completion:nil)
}

override func presentationTransitionDidEnd(completed: Bool)
{
    if !completed {
        self.dimmingView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}

override func dismissalTransitionDidEnd(completed: Bool)
{
    self.dimmingView.removeFromSuperview()
}

override func dismissalTransitionWillBegin() {
    presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator().animateAlongsideTransition({context in
        self.dimmingView.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)
}

func closePresented() {
    var presenting = self.presentingViewController

   presentedViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

override func sizeForChildContentContainer(container: UIContentContainer!, withParentContainerSize parentSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    var size : CGSize

    switch self.controllerStyle {
    case .Left, .Right:
        size = CGSizeMake(self.shortest, parentSize.height)

    case .Bottom, .Top:
        size = CGSizeMake(parentSize.width, self.shortest)

    default:
        size = CGSizeMake(parentSize.width, parentSize.height)
    }

    return size
}

override func frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView() -> CGRect {
    var frame : CGRect
    var size = sizeForChildContentContainer(nil, withParentContainerSize: containerView.bounds.size)

    switch self.controllerStyle {
    case .Left:
        frame = CGRectMake(containerView.bounds.size.width - size.width, 0, size.width, size.height)

    case .Right:
        frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)

    case .Bottom:
        frame = CGRectMake(0, containerView.bounds.size.height - size.height, size.width, size.height)

    case .Top:
        frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)

    default:
        frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    }
    return frame
}
```

Comment: Sry, accidentaly posted before I was done writing.

Comment: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; should bring you to the previous view.

Comment: Try passing just `"hideList"` as the selector, that is, drop the `Selector()`.  Also, pass `nil` as the completion handler to `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

Comment: The selector is running as it should, and I have tried nil as completion handler, no difference. (As I stated above, this code works if I comment out the custom TransitioningDelegate.

Answer (score 4):

Try enabling zombie objects in your scheme settings. (Remember to turn it off when you're done because that change won't show up in your source control and you really don't want to release an app without ARC!)

If you get the error message

```
-[_UILayoutGuide superview]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1781ac6a0
```

then just add this code to the view controller being dismissed:

```
deinit {
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

`UILayoutGuide` is a private autolayout class. I believe this to be a bug (and filed it as such), since why would a dismissed view controller have any need for autolayout? Removing a class from its superview will preemptively prevent the autolayout constraints from being accessed after they've been deallocated.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 1.1**

Try using in completion params instead of `nil` use `{}`. For example: 
`presentedViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})`

Answer (score 1):

Before dismissing the viewController,you should set TransitioningDelegate nil.

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue.
I had to declare class variable

```
class firstVC : UIViewController
{
    let customTransitioninDelegate = customTransitioninDelegate().
...

    //Then when created second view controller just assign it
    -func xxx()
    { 
        var secondVC = secondVC();
        secondVC.transitioningDelegate = customTransitioninDelegate;
        self.presentViewController(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil); 
    }
}
class secondVC: UIViewController
{
...
    func xxx()
    {
        if(self.presentingViewController != nil)
        {
            self.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
        }
    }
}
```

And the dismiss works.

Comment: Didnt work for me, don't belive this is the solution